# do I need a preExecute() function in action class to check proper credentials in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

to implement credentials do I need to implement a preExecute function like this:

```
public function preExecute() {
        $this->configuration = new jobGeneratorConfiguration();
        if (!$this->getUser()->hasCredential(
                        $this->configuration->getCredentials($this->getActionName())

            ));
    }
```

Or is it suffice to have it defined in the module/config/security.yml like this:

```
all:
  is_secure:   true
  credentials: [ admin ]
```

However I am not able to work it out using security.yml only! I thought preExecute is not necessary and symfony automatically handles it by loading the security.yml definition!
Please help!

I am using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin and sfForkedDoctrineApply plugin..

Comment: Just to check, have you tried doing `./symfony cc`?

Comment: @lonesomeday: actually I figured out the problem just now, it was the is_super_admin field in sf_guard_user table which was set to 1 for all my dummy users in fixture.yml :) ! that's why every users were getting the access to all modules bypassing the credentials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to do a pre-execute for this.

The security.yml file is enough to stop people without the appropriate credentials from getting to the specified module or action.

Comment: You are right! thanks for your answer. The problem was that is_admin field was set to 1 in sfGuardUser and therefore the user was able to bypass all credentials :)